# TYPO3 protected sites access to GET variables

Tags: php, typo3

I am writing an TYPO3 Extension and everything is working fine right now. I Access the GET Variables via

```
t3lib_div::_GET('rid');
```

This does work on the testsite I added my Extension to, but if I add it on another subsite of the same page which is in an access-restricted area this does not work. I use var_dump to look at the GET vars, and on the normal site it works, on the restricted I dont get anything (not even NULL!) Just no output and the logic also does not take it.  How do i fix that, or ist there another way to access the GET variables in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that happens because within the first request the output of your extensions is stored within the cache. And the second output is just generated out of the cache (instead of regeneration within your extension). To avoid that you could just make your Extensions not cacheable (USER_INT) or use cHash to show that cache-entries are related to more input values than just the simple page-url...

cHash is explained in the [the mysteries of cHash](https://typo3.org/documentation/article/the-mysteries-of-chash-1) article and I guess you'll find enough information regarding USER vs. USER_INT Objects with google ;)

Comment: right now it is just running with nocache but user_int and chash should be better, i think i will try that chash thing, as the article says it is fastest, and it sounds pretty good. Thank you for the link

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why, but seems to be some kind of caching issue. I always cleared the Typo3 cache so it was not directly a problem with that, but if i set the "nocache" flag for the site the plugin is on, everything works fine. So actually it has nothing to do with the access thing, but I do not understand why this doesnt work without nocache.